# Memory leak when Camera.targetTexture = new RenderTexture(...)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

I have written an EditorWindow that renders the view of a camera into an additional editor window. In order to adapt instantly when the window is resized, the target texture of the camera is reassigned (actually it is only done when necessary) at tick time to demonstrate the problem:

```
public class PlayerViewWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private Camera PlayerViewCamera; // References a camera in the scene

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture = new RenderTexture((int)position.width, (int)position.height, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
        PlayerViewCamera.Render();
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, position.width, position.height), PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture);       
    }
}
```

When I activate this window the reassignment of the camera target texture causes a memory leak. So: why is the old target texture not garbage collected? 
Is there a way to explicitly destroy the old target texture?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`RenderTexture` Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html):

> As with other "native engine object" types, it is important to pay attention to the lifetime of any render textures and release them when you are finished using them with the Release function, as they will not be garbage collected like normal managed types.

So just call [`Release()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.Release.html) on the old `RenderTexture` before attaching the new one:

```
public class PlayerViewWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private Camera PlayerViewCamera; // References a camera in the scene

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        if(PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture != null)
        {
            PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture.Release();
        }

        PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture = new RenderTexture((int)position.width, (int)position.height, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
        PlayerViewCamera.Render();
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, position.width, position.height), PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to free the `RenderTexture` after using it like [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080903/3785314) said in his answer. Unfortunately it is expensive to create and destroy `RenderTexture` each time `OnGUI` is called and `OnGUI` is even called more often than the `Update` function.

It would be better to get a temporary Render with `RenderTexture.GetTemporary` then release it with `RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary` when you're done using it. *Note that there was a bug with the `RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary` function on some platforms in the past. I assume it is now fixed but if you run into issues with it then stick with the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080903/3785314) solution.*

```
public class PlayerViewWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private Camera PlayerViewCamera; // References a camera in the scene

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        Vector2 size = new Vector2(position.width, position.width);
        //Get temporary RenderTexture
        RenderTexture tempRT = RenderTexture.GetTemporary((int)size.x, (int)size.y, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
        PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture = tempRT;
        PlayerViewCamera.Render();
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.x), PlayerViewCamera.targetTexture);
        //Release temporary RenderTexture
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(tempRT);
    }
}
```